# Decorators or subclassing is best pattern for React.Component

Tags: javascript, inheritance, reactjs, ecmascript-6, decorator

Which is the recommended way and why?

way_1:(Using inheritance)

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {

    //Other functions

    log = (msg) => {
        console.log(`[${this.constructor.name}]`, msg);
    }

    //Other functions
}

export default BaseComponent;


class XyzComponent extends BaseComponent {

    //Other functions

    someFunction = () => {
        this.log("Some log");
    }

    //Other functions
}

export default XyzComponent;
```

way_2:(Using decorators)

```
function withLog(ComposedComponent) {
    return class withLog extends Component {
        log = (msg) => {
            console.log(`[${this.constructor.name}]`, msg);
        }
    }
};

export default withLog;

@withLog
class XyzComponent extends React.Component {

    //Other functions

    someFunction = () => {
        this.log("Some log");
    }

    //Other functions
}
```

I liked way_1 because it looks like other OOPs based languages. Which makes constancy and easier to understand. But everywhere else people saying about decorators. So I'm bit confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People likely reccomend decorators because they internalize the functionality you want.

When you inherit from `BaseComponent` in your first example you're creating a strong (inheritence) dependency between `XyzComponent` and `BaseComponent`. Then, any changes to `BaseComponent` may have an indirect effect on `XyzComponent`s.

A more likely scenario is if--later down the line--you decide to change `XyzComponent`'s logging method. If you took the first approach it might be difficult to "cut out the middle" and inherit from `React.Component` because other parts of your codebase might be accessing `XyzComponent` through its `BaseComponent` superclass. In that case, you'd have to ensure that your modifications don't violate `BaseComponent`'s contract.

So, although the inheritence approach is easy to grasp and very OO it *might* cause headaches later. If you're aware of those headaches make a judgement call - I personally find inheritence to be self-explanatory wheras the decorators are a little more indirect.

(This answer can be summed up as: "Prefer composition over inheritence")